# One script to many html files to load

Tags: javascript, html

I got a script for loading a html files to my page. Everything is work, but i want a something like "loop" to load every position in my list.

So i got a script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#introduction").click(function(){
        $("#main_info").load("introduction.html");
      });
    });
    </script>
```

And I load a position from menu "introduction.

```
  <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="home"><i class="home"></i>home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="introduction"><i class="introduction"></i>introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="structure"><i class="structure"></i>structure</a></li>
        </ul>
```

But how to change this script for try use every position in my UL LI A?

like when i click a li with home i will load home.html, introduction = introduction.html and structure = structure.html??

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("a").click(function (){
 $(this).find("i").load($(this).attr("id")+".html");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this "loop" logic using `.each()` from `JQuery` just like that:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li a').each(function() {  // <-- Iterate throught all your links
    $(this).click(function(){
      var fileToLoad = $(this).attr('id') + '.html';
      $("#main_info").load(fileToLoad);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="home"><i class="home"></i>home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="introduction"><i class="introduction"></i>introduction</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="structure"><i class="structure"></i>structure</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you also help me when i here can add a folder 
where will I get these files from? like ./content/file.html ?

Comment: @Rodriquez Not a good practice but in your case you can simply write this path in the id like this: `<a href="#" id="./content/file">`

Comment: @Rodriquez ,you can add # in href like `<a href="#./content/file">` and in jQuery, `$(this).attr("href").replace("#","")`